# Why is my write to file function overriding my previous file text?

Tags: python, file-io, tuples

I'm trying to add user entered data to a tuple, then write that tuple on a line in my text file. I'm doing something wrong because only the last call is added to the txt file. Here's my functions:

```
def write_to_file(tuple1):
    with open('student_info.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(' '.join(x for x in tuple1))
        f.write("\n")

def get_student_info(student_name):
    tuple1 = ()
    tuple1 = tuple1 + (student_name,)

    print("\nScores for " + student_name)
    print("Enter a test score (or enter Stop to stop):")
    count = 2

    test_score = input("Test score 1: ")
    tuple1 = tuple1 + (test_score,)
    while not test_score == "stop" and not test_score == "Stop":
        test_score = input("Test score " + str(count) + ": ")
        count = count + 1
        tuple1 = tuple1 + (test_score,)

    last_item = len(tuple1) - 1
    tuple1 = tuple1[:last_item]

    write_to_file(tuple1)

def read_from_file():
    with open('student_info.txt', 'r') as f:
        f_contents = f.read()
        print(f_contents, end=" ")
```

And here's my calls in the main section:

```
open("student_info.txt", "w").close()
student_name = ""
get_student_info("Jenny: ")
get_student_info("Dave: ")
get_student_info("Sammy: ")
get_student_info("Brooke: ")
read_from_file()
```

My student_info.txt just ends up reading "Brooke:" and then the data added to the tuple on the last call.

Comment: Opening a file in `w` mode erases the file. Use `a` mode to append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append to a file you need to change the ‘w’ to an ‘a’ for append when you want to write to the file.